# change the width and height of text area

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Im having MVC5 application with bootstrap3 and one of the fields should have long text box,

currently Im using the following code and when I try to change the width to 1000 noting happen.in addtion i've tried to remove the col-md-10 class and beside that the textbox
move bit to left nothing happen...

I want to change it to be bigger,how should I do that ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting a fixed width on the TextArea would defeat the purpose of responsiveness that bootstrap brings to your application. You should add "form-control" to the class to make the textarea fill the its container.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Another option is to declare your own custom css style and use it on the textarea

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "custom-width" })
```

Style

```
.custom-width {
    width: 700px !important; <-- add important!
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I even try to change it to width: 1800px !important; and nothing was changed ,any idea what can couse to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px !important;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

PS : note the use of the !important keyword

Comment: The `!important` keyword should only be used if there is absolutely no other option. And there is usually another option...